# Is it possible to see a who has purchased an app in the iTunes Connect financial report?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, license

Our company requires to book every sale we make in our SAP system against a customer name. So when we publish the apps under our developer license, we will need the information of each customer who bought the app.

Is there a way Apple will give me detailed information?

Answer (score 2):

**No.** The only way to get the name of someone who's purchased your app is to request it from the user when they open the app.